# Mobile Menu issues / Icon not displaying

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having a hard time figuring out why the mobile menu icon will not display on the following site:

You will see if you resize down to a smaller size that in the top right corner there is a link which does bring up the mobile menu.  The image that is supposed to show there does not though.

```
#nav-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
display: block;
width: 54px;
height: 44px;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -9999px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
background: url('http://www.cap-acp.org/_images/icon-res-menu.png') center center no-repeat;  }  

   @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 .js #nav {
   position: relative;
 }
 .js #nav.closed {
   max-height: none;
 }
 #nav-toggle {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is a transparent .png with only white bars, so it's there but you can't see it against a white background. You can verify this by adding a background color to your background CSS declaration, for example:

```
background: red url('http://www.cap-acp.org/_images/icon-res-menu.png') center center no-repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

Josh is right. If you change the image, it should show up fine.

```
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 44px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;

  /* I changed the background src to a different hamburger and it works fine */
  background: url('https://www.elavon.com/images/icon-mobile-menu-off.svg') center center no-repeat; 
}  

@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .js #nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js #nav.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  #nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}
```